# How to put a white border to Black ellipse in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

[image]

I am using the above given popup in my windows phone 8 application. My issue is for the black color list item, it is not possible to differentiate the item from other items. So my question is how i can put a rounded white border to this particular black list item.

Here is the template what i am using in my application.

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorListTemplate">
    <Grid Height="70" Margin="0,0,0,5" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Ellipse Height="52" Width="52" Fill="{Binding SelectedColor}"/>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ColorName}" Margin="32,0" FontSize="34" Style="{StaticResource NormalText}"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckedStatus}" Style="{StaticResource            CheckBoxStyle}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Anyone please help me to design my requirement.

Comment: Could you just set the stroke on the ellipse elements, `<Ellipse Height="52" Width="52" Fill="{Binding SelectedColor}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>`

Comment: If you add this as answer, i can mark it as answered

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could set a colored `Stroke` on the `Ellipse` elements to make it stand out on the black background.

Example:

```
 <Ellipse Height="52" Width="52" Fill="{Binding SelectedColor}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
```