# Is there something for Ellipse as Rect is for Rectangle?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I know that there's a `Rect` to define the location and size of a `Rectangle`.

But if there's something that's for a `Ellipse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply have the `Ellipse` tag for you to work around with it.

For more refer this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207026(v=vs.105).aspx#tag_ellipses) from msdn.

[How to put a white border to Black ellipse in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142218/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know how `Ellipse` works. What I want is a way to Arrange (ArrangeOverride) elements using a round shape instead of a `Rect`.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. ArrangeOverride always takes a parameter of type Size, so the element will always be rectangular. You might use an ellipse with transparent background to make it visually round, but in layout it will always take rectangular shape.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek, that's a great explaination.